# Java -Version? How does it gives installed java version details

Tags: java

we run java program in cmd using java , same way for finding installed java version we use Java -version in cmd, So how does it gives us version details? Is there any Version class defined in java API ?Its seems funny Question though

Comment: No, it's not in the API. It's just printing values baked into the `java` binary when it was compiled.

Comment: Related: [Getting version of java in runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2591083/3788176).

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13851817/4491066

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
System.getProperty("java.vendor")
System.getProperty("java.version")
System.getProperty("java.vm.vendor")
System.getProperty("java.vm.name")
System.getProperty("java.vm.version")
System.getProperty("os.name")
System.getProperty("os.version")
System.getProperty("os.arch")
```

And for getting the default character encoding

```
new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream()).getEncoding()
```

Comment: Even the default character encoding may be got from the standard System Property "file.encoding".

Answer (score 0):

Java stores the version into the `java.exe`. In case you want to try for yourself just open the `java.exe` into any text editor or hex editor and you will find version written inside it.